# JQuery Post inside Promise inside each How to create array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, promise

I have some code

```
function getSomeInfoFromDB() {
    let promises = [];
    let order = [];
    $("tr").each(function(index) {
        let value1 = $(this).children("td:nth-child(4)").text();
        let value2 = $(this).children("td:nth-child(5)").text();

        order.push({
            index: index,
            a: value1,
            b: value2,
            promiseResult: ""
        });
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve) =>
$.post("http://url.com/getDataFromDataBase.php", {a: value2})
            .done(resolve)));

    });

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(values => values)
        .then(result => $(order).each(function() {
            this.promiseResult = result;
        }))
        .then(console.log(order));
}
```

I need save index, value1, value2, and PromiseResult (DataBase answer for this $each iteration) 
for each TR element into associative array or something
I cant get right result.

I need something like this array - `order[{index: 1, a: value1forIndex1 , b: value2forIndex1, promiseResult: REZULT1} ,{index: 2, a: value1forIndex2 , b: value2forIndex2, promiseResult: REZULT2}]`

Comment: Is there any reason you want to wait for all of the promises to resolve before collating the results? Actually, is there any reason you're instantiating and using promises at all?

Comment: big problem is that I need get all info from database, for any tr. Then I need create some XML document from all data, and then send this full document  to other server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you are asking for

```
function getSomeInfoFromDB() {
  var promises = $('tr').map((index, elem) => {
    let val1 = $(elem).children("td:nth-child(4)").text();
    let val2 = $(elem).children("td:nth-child(5)").text();
    return $.post('http://url.com/getDataFromDataBase.php', { a: val2 }).then(result => {
      return {
        index: index,
        a: val1,
        b: val2,
        result: result
      };
    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(arr => {
      console.log(arr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks cool, but how can I set POST param, I need get post param from each tr>td:nth-child(4)

Comment: I updated my answer, I didn't see that you were passing params in the post request. sorry about that

Comment: Dont work. In all except Index it get clean " " result

Object
a:""
b:""
index:3
result:""

Comment: I made another update, the issue was the use of the this keyword.